# I have a problem with EditText in Android Studio Fragment that if I can't type in it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-xml

The problem is when I click on the EditText box in the fragment, the keyboard appears and then hides it immediately, so I can't type in it.

What is the problem please help me?

Comment: Can you share the layout for your that fragment involved ?

Comment: I sent you the layout for EditText on the same page as the question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384409/i-have-a-problem-with-edittext-in-android-studio-fragment-that-if-i-cant-type-i?answertab=active#tab-top)                       @TicherhazFreePalestine

Answer (score 0):

This is layout for EditText : [Ticherhaz FreePalestine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9346054/ticherhaz-freepalestine)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/b2"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchUsersBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btns_style2"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:hint="ادخل اسم الشخص"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```